# How to stop google sheets resizing an image with =image("url")?

Tags: google-sheets, images, imgur

This sheet shows the problem:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G_SXx_poARQ4muv3wxopV-zsSOoRwdNgssrvnfFOCVg/edit?usp=sharing

I have an image that is 41px by 1637px (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vklJ4.png) and I want to put it in a cell on the sheet that's also 1637px tall. However, when I use `=image()` to add the image, it's much smaller than that - and if I force it to be 1637px tall again, it looks really blurry, exactly as though I've resized up a much smaller picture.

How can I stop google resizing the image when it first imports it, so that I can make the image appear at its original size without looking blurry?

Edit for clarity:

The original image is 41px by 1637px tall. Using `=image("url",3)` displays an image in google sheets that is much smaller than this, even though the 3 should display the image at its original size.

Using `=image("url",1)` to resize the image to fit the size of the cell produces an image that is 1637px tall, but is very blurry because it's stretching the small image instead of displaying the actual original image size I want.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The formula bar might show a formula helper showing the parameters  of IMAGE and a link to the [help article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en) with the complete details.  Please read the help article. If you needs further help, please show what IMAGE parameters have you used.

Comment: Hi @Rubén, thank you for the welcome and the help link. Unfortunately it doesn't cover the problem I'm having, but I've edited the original question to show the parameters I used.

Comment: I think that the problem comes from imgur as opening the image link actually opens a web page including the image in an img tag with size attributes, so it's very likely that imgur is sending  the image to Google servers that is shown in Google Sheets. I don't know if imgur offer a different link pointing directly to the original image with no resizing / optimization.

Comment: Hi and welcome. A VERY important line in the documentation-`no mode causes the cell to be resized to fit the image.` May I suggest you take a blank spreadsheet and reproduce the examples in the [documentation for the IMAGE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333). I found that the images shown in the "Result" column did not _initially_ resemble my spreadsheet. I had to resize the cells to get them to match. Your IMGUR image is crystal clear when the formula = `=image("https://i.imgur.com/dVhtrwT.png", 4, 1637, 41)` and row is resized to 1637 pixels and Column to 41 pixels.

Comment: Thank you both for you help, Tedinoz' instructions made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=image("https://i.imgur.com/dVhtrwT.png", 4, 1637, 41)
```

If you resize the cell, (e.g. 100,41) you'll see only the top section of the image, but still "crystal clear".